# Specify multiple options in a Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

I have specified the following grunt task:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function() {
  var apiUrl = grunt.option('api') || 'default';
  var local = grunt.option('local');
  grunt.log.writeln('Using api url: ' + apiUrl);
  grunt.log.writeln('Using local: ' + local);
});
```

`local` is supposed to be a boolean value.

The value of the parameters depends on the order on the command line. This behaviour is unwanted.

If I put the `local` parameter last, everything works as expected:

```
$ grunt build --api localhost --local
Running "build" task
Using api url: localhost
Using local: true
```

Otherwise the values get screwed up:

```
$ grunt build --local --api localhost
Warning: Task "localhost" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
$ grunt build --local --api=localhost
Running "build" task
Using api url: default
Using local: --api=localhost

Done, without errors.
```

I could use a target instead of the boolean option, but I want to know what's going on.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug and understood that I have to always give a value to the parameter (dans use the "="):

Transform :

```
grunt build --api localhost --local
```

in

```
grunt build --api=localhost --local=true
```